# Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed for android 2.2.2 in window 32 bit

Tags: android

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible
>   with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's
>   system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64
>   (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software
>   publisher

Answer (score 0):

It requires JDK latest JDK version I.E 1.8:

Install jdk1.8,

In AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location, select your directory where the JKD is located,

Click Ok.